# wchar_t and POSIX library

Tags: c++, c

There is the POSIX library in c++ support wchar_t? if not, then how is it possible to solve this problem?

For example, I need open `opendir(wchar_t*)`

Comment: What problem?  (More characters to keep the site happy.)

Comment: What is "this problem" anyway?

Comment: With the addition, why do you expect `opendir(wchar_t*)` to do anyway? POSIX specifies that file "names" are just sequences of bytes, and `wchar_t*` doesn't point to a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no POSIX wchar_t version of opendir.  Your platform may have one if you are lucky.  Otherwise, you'll have to use something like the iconv library to convert your wide character string into UTF-8 (or whatever character encoding your file system API uses).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking.

POSIX incorporates the C standard as a base document, and the C standard specifies `wchar_t` and numerous functions that operate on `wchar_t` values.  So in this sense, `wchar_t` is certainly suppported by POSIX.

Comment: POSIX is also slightly-incompatible with C++ (different evolutionary paths from C89). You can often ignore this in practice, though.

Comment: I mean, I need open opendir(wchar_t)